# If a mapping from positive integers to a cyclic group fails to be injective, show that the group is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

let $G=\langle a\rangle$ be a cyclic group generated by $a$. Given that $\phi:n\rightarrow a^n$ is a mapping of additive group of all integers $I$ onto $G$. If $\phi$ is not one-one prove that $G$ is a finite cyclic group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\phi$ is not one-one, there are $m,n$ with $m\lt n$ such that $a^m=\phi(m)=\phi(n)=a^n$. What is $a^{n-m}$? What does that tell you about the order of $G$?

Comment: as $\phi$ is not one-one, $a^{n-m}\ne 1$ , but i am not able to see  why will that mean $G$ is finite

Comment: Actually $a^{n-m}=1$. Now let $d$ be the minimal positive integer such that $a^d=1$ and note that $G=\{a^k:k\in\Bbb Z\}$. Use the division algorithm in $\Bbb Z$ to show that every element of $G$ can be expressed as $a^t$ with $0\le t\lt d$, then this will imply $G=\{1, a, a^2, ..., a^{d-1}\}$.

Comment: but, $a^{n-m}=1$ would imply that $a^{n-m}=a^0$ which means $n=m$ , but this should not b true as $\phi$ is not one-one  ?

Comment: Why does $a^{n-m}=a^0$ imply $n=m$?

Comment: because $n-m=0$ which means $n=m$ ??

Comment: @AmanMittal $$a^{n-m} = a^0 \Leftrightarrow n=m \qquad \forall\ n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$$ if and only if $G$ is non cyclic.

Comment: Why does $a^{n-m}=a^0$ imply $n-m=0$?

Comment: equating the powers ? lol, i know i am terribly wrong. please bare with me !!

Comment: $1^2=1^3$ does not imply that $2=3$.

Comment: $(-1)^2=(-1)^4$ does that imply $2=4$?

Comment: of course not !, so the condition is $a\ne \pm 1$ how does it relate with the need that the group should be non-cyclic for this to work ?

Comment: The point is $a^n=a^m$ does not imply $n=m$!

Comment: never ? but we do it for non-cyclic groups

Comment: Unless you are given extra conditions which imply it, never! And we certainly don't do it for non-cyclic groups either. For example in $S_3$, $(123)^0=(123)^3=(123)^{3n}$.

Comment: ok, i think i get it now. I will definitely re-look at the proofs i have done before. Thanks a lot for helping me though this.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\phi$ fails to be injective. That means we have integers $n<m$ such that $m=n+k$ and

$$a^n=a^{m}\Rightarrow a^n=a^na^k\Rightarrow a^k=1$$

so $G$ is finite.